# How can I make my If … Then statement dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub ValidateCode()    
    Dim list, llist, lllist As String, result, rresult, rrresult As String

    list = Range("J12").Value    
    llist = Range("J18").Value    
    lllist = Range("J24").Value

    'Division    
    If list = Range("E2").Value Then result = Range("D2").Value    
    If list = Range("E3").Value Then result = Range("D3").Value    
    If list = Range("E4").Value Then result = Range("D4").Value    
    If list = Range("E5").Value Then result = Range("D5").Value    
    If list = Range("E6").Value Then result = Range("D6").Value    
    If list = Range("E7").Value Then result = Range("D7").Value    
    If list = Range("E8").Value Then result = Range("D8").Value    
    If list = Range("E9").Value Then result = Range("D9").Value    
    If list = Range("E10").Value Then result = Range("D10").Value    
    If list = Range("E11").Value Then result = Range("D11").Value    
    If list = Range("E12").Value Then result = Range("D12").Value    
    If list = Range("E13").Value Then result = Range("D13").Value    
    If list = Range("E14").Value Then result = Range("D14").Value    
    If list = Range("E15").Value Then result = Range("D15").Value    
    If list = Range("E16").Value Then result = Range("D16").Value    
    If list = Range("E17").Value Then result = Range("D17").Value    
    If list = Range("E18").Value Then result = Range("D18").Value    
    If list = Range("E19").Value Then result = Range("D19").Value    
    If list = Range("E20").Value Then result = Range("D20").Value    
    f list = Range("E21").Value Then result = Range("D21").Value    
    If list = Range("E22").Value Then result = Range("D22").Value    
    If list = Range("E23").Value Then result = Range("D23").Value        

    'Product Category    
    If llist = Range("E26").Value Then rresult = Range("D26").Value    
    If llist = Range("E27").Value Then rresult = Range("D27").Value    
    If llist = Range("E28").Value Then rresult = Range("D28").Value    
    If llist = Range("E29").Value Then rresult = Range("D29").Value    
    If llist = Range("E30").Value Then rresult = Range("D30").Value    
    If llist = Range("E31").Value Then rresult = Range("D31").Value    
    If llist = Range("E32").Value Then rresult = Range("D32").Value    
    If llist = Range("E33").Value Then rresult = Range("D33").Value    
    If llist = Range("E34").Value Then rresult = Range("D34").Value    
    If llist = Range("E35").Value Then rresult = Range("D35").Value    
    If llist = Range("E36").Value Then rresult = Range("D36").Value    
    If llist = Range("E37").Value Then rresult = Range("D37").Value    
    If llist = Range("E38").Value Then rresult = Range("D38").Value    
    If llist = Range("E39").Value Then rresult = Range("D39").Value    
    If llist = Range("E40").Value Then rresult = Range("D40").Value    
    If llist = Range("E41").Value Then rresult = Range("D41").Value    
    If llist = Range("E42").Value Then rresult = Range("D42").Value    
    If llist = Range("E43").Value Then rresult = Range("D43").Value    
    If llist = Range("E44").Value Then rresult = Range("D44").Value    
    If llist = Range("E45").Value Then rresult = Range("D45").Value    
    If llist = Range("E46").Value Then rresult = Range("D46").Value    
    If llist = Range("E47").Value Then rresult = Range("D47").Value    
    If llist = Range("E48").Value Then rresult = Range("D48").Value    
    If llist = Range("E49").Value Then rresult = Range("D49").Value    
    If llist = Range("E50").Value Then rresult = Range("D50").Value    
    If llist = Range("E51").Value Then rresult = Range("D51").Value    
    f llist = Range("E52").Value Then rresult = Range("D52").Value    
    If llist = Range("E54").Value Then rresult = Range("D54").Value    
    If llist = Range("E55").Value Then rresult = Range("D55").Value    
    If llist = Range("E56").Value Then rresult = Range("D56").Value    
    If llist = Range("E57").Value Then rresult = Range("D57").Value

    'Brand Name    
    If lllist = Range("B2").Value Then rrresult = Range("A2").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B3").Value Then rrresult = Range("A3").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B4").Value Then rrresult = Range("A4").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B5").Value Then rrresult = Range("A5").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B6").Value Then rrresult = Range("A6").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B7").Value Then rrresult = Range("A7").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B8").Value Then rrresult = Range("A8").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B9").Value Then rrresult = Range("A9").Value    
    f lllist = Range("B10").Value Then rrresult = Range("A10").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B11").Value Then rrresult = Range("A11").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B12").Value Then rrresult = Range("A12").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B13").Value Then rrresult = Range("A13").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B14").Value Then rrresult = Range("A14").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B15").Value Then rrresult = Range("A15").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B16").Value Then rrresult = Range("A16").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B17").Value Then rrresult = Range("A17").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B18").Value Then rrresult = Range("A18").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B19").Value Then rrresult = Range("A19").Value    
    If lllist = Range("B20").Value Then rrresult = Range("A20").Value

    Range("J8").Value = result + rresult + rrresult    
    MsgBox "Cost Unit Code is " & Range("J8").Value
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**See the Use of Loops in VBA**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ValidateCode()

Dim list As String, llist As String, lllist As String
Dim result As String, rresult As String, rrresult As String
Dim i As Long

list = Range("J12").Value
llist = Range("J18").Value
lllist = Range("J24").Value

'Division

For i = 2 To 23
    If list = Range("E" & i).Value Then result = Range("D" & i).Value
Next

'Product Category
For i = 26 To 57
    If llist = Range("E" & i).Value Then rresult = Range("D" & i).Value
Next

'Brand Name
For i = 2 To 20
    If lllist = Range("B" & i).Value Then rrresult = Range("A" & i).Value
Next

Range("J8").Value = result + rresult + rrresult

MsgBox "Cost Unit Code is " & Range("J8").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: Note that if you `Dim list, llist, lllist As String` only `lllist` is declared as `String` but the first 2 are declared as `Variant` in VBA you need to specify a type for **every** variable otherwise it is `Variant` by default! • Also `i` should be declared `As Long` • I recommend always to activate `Option Explicit`: In the VBA editor go to *Tools* › *Options* › *[Require Variable Declaration](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/option-explicit.html)* to force a proper variable declaration.

Comment: Actually the `result` variables should probably even be `Double` since they are used to get the sum `result + rresult + rrresult`. Therefore strings wolud cast into a numeric anyway here.

Comment: What if I'm getting data from another sheet?